# Populate dropdown in Jtable with Jquery

Tags: java, jquery-jtable

I have a jsp page **material.jsp** with following code snippet :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#MaterialTableContainer').jtable({
            title : 'Table of Materials',
            actions : {
                listAction : 'CRUDControllerForMaterial?action=list',
                createAction : 'CRUDControllerForMaterial?action=create',
                updateAction : 'CRUDControllerForMaterial?action=update',
                deleteAction : 'CRUDControllerForMaterial?action=delete' },
            fields : {  
                id : {
                    title : 'ID',
                    key : true,
                    list : true,
                    create : true
                },
                materialName : {
                    title : 'MaterialName',
                    width : '30%',
                    edit : true
                },
                description : {
                    title : 'Description',
                    width : '30%',
                    edit : true
                },
                lastModifiedComments : {
                    title : 'LastModifiedComments',
                    width : '20%',
                    edit : true
                },
                materialClassID : {
                    title : 'MaterialClassID',
                    width : '50%',
                    edit : true,
                    options : ["1","2","3","4","5"]
                },
                isMaster : {
                    title : 'IsMaster',
                    width : '50%',
                    edit : true
                }

        }});
        $('#MaterialTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
</script>
```

Now, in this, I want **materialClassID** to be a dropdown. So, in **options**, I have hard-coded values as **["1","2","3","4","5"]**.

But, these **values are to be dynamic**, i.e., these values should be fetched from the server (servlet) at runtime. So, how can I make a call to a function at this point, and retrieve the list/result-set.

**We are using servlet-jsp, so I would need to write the code in Java.**

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make an ajax call to a servlet (or jsp) that yields the appropriate dynamic JSON?

Comment: Hi Elliott, thanks for quick response. Could you provide me code snippet for how to make that call. Thanks

Comment: From which side? The `$.getJSON()` or a servlet that uses something like [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

Comment: Why not have the jQuery call a servlet? I'm confused by what you're asking me here.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me call the php to return the needed data.

```
 materialClassID : {
                title : 'MaterialClassID',
                width : '50%',
                edit : true,
                options : 'http://sample.com/sample.php?get=numbers'
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (assuming you've fetched your jsonMatArray already) -

```
materialClassID : {
  title : 'MaterialClassID',
  width : '50%',
  edit : true
}
materialClassID.prototype.options = jsonMatArray;
```

or (the more usual) -

```
materialClassID : {
  title : 'MaterialClassID',
  width : '50%',
  edit : true,
  options : jsonMatArray
}
```